# Calculus operations in Excel and Sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets, microsoft, integration

I am having issues with integration in Google Sheets and Microsoft Excel. I have installed the necessary packages to compute integrals and double integrals, including Calculus Functions for Google Sheets and Excelab from ExcelWorks for Microsoft Excel. I am trying to compute a double integral for the following equation:

[image: double integral screenshot]

For the variables, I have them saved into columns in the spreadsheet. For example, the first set of values would be: ylc is 1, delta y is 2, xlc is 1, delta x is 2, n and m alternate between 0 and 1, h1 and h2 are 4. When I calculate the integral by hand, I get 4, 2.546, 2.546, 1.6211.

In the spreadsheets, the first integral is calculated appropriately, but the second integration on the next variable is always 0.  True values of function with respect to n,m values and calculation after integration of inside and outside integrals

[image]

In the equations, the variables for x and y are set to empty cells in the spreadsheets, AZ1 and BA1 respectively. The function for the integration is stored in column AW as

```
=COS(W2*PI()*AZ1/H2)*COS(V2*PI()*BA1/I2)
```

The first integral is stored in AX as

```
=QUADF(AW2, AZ1, AS2-(AU2/2),AS2+(AU2/2))
```

The second order integral is stored in AY as

```
=QUADF(AX2, BA1, AT2-(AV2/2), AT2+(AV2/2))
```

which is then calculated as `0`, where column `V` is `m`, `W` is `n`, `H` is `h1`, `I` is `h2`.

[image: Error values calculated for double integral]

Any help pointing me in the direction of solving this issue would be appreciated. Ideally I would like to solve this in Excel because I reach a calculation limit in Sheets. I am using these calculations for dozens of values of x, y, n, and m so automation is a necessity.